# Failed to get result of stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I created a procedure that returns the ID of the Question based on the input text

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetQuestionIDbyTekst]
(
    @Tekst nvarchar(100)
)
AS
    DECLARE @QuestionID int

    SELECT QuestionID 
    FROM dbo.Questions 
    WHERE Tekst = @Tekst 

    RETURN @QuestionID
```

and I have a problem in getting the value of the `QuestionID`:

```
 public static int getQuestionID(Question p)
 {   
       using (Entities dm = new Entities())
       {
           return dm.GetQuestionIDbyTekst(p.Tekst);          
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the `@QuestionID` as `Output` parameter. Also you need to assign the result to `@QuestionID`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetQuestionIDbyTekst]
(
    @Tekst nvarchar(100),
    @QuestionID INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @QuestionID int
SELECT @QuestionID = QuestionID FROM dbo.Questions WHERE Tekst = @Tekst 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetQuestionIDbyTekst]
(
    @Tekst nvarchar(100)
)
AS
   -- DECLARE @QuestionID int

    SELECT QuestionID 
    FROM dbo.Questions 
    WHERE Tekst = @Tekst 

  --  RETURN @QuestionID
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explain how it works, and describe when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your variant of the stored procedure.

And if you use ADO.NET and want to get return value, try this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\***;Initial Catalog=***;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;");
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetQuestionIDbyTekst", con);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tekst", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "eee";

SqlParameter returnPar = new SqlParameter();
returnPar.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(retturnPar);

cmd.ExecuteScalar();
var result = returnPar.Value;
```

If you use Entity Framework, you may use this variant:

```
    public static int GetQuestionIDbyTekst(string question)
    {
        using (var context = new EfDbContext())
        {
            var test = new SqlParameter("@Tekst", question);

            var resultParam = new SqlParameter("@result", SqlDbType.Int);
            resultParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec @result = [dbo].[testProc] @Tekst", resultParam, test);
            return (int)resultParam.Value;
        }
    }
```